# why dont nullable strings have a hasValue() method?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have a class which contains a nullable strings, I want to make a check to see whether they stay null or somebody has set them.

simliar to strings, the class contains integers which are nullable, where i can perform this check by doing an equality comparison 
with the .HasValue() method -  it seems like strings dont have this?

So how do check whether it goes from null to notNull?

```
public class Test 
{
    public string? a
    public string? b
    public int? c
} 

var oldQ = new Test(c=123)
var newQ = new Test(c=546)

bool isStilValid = newQ.c.HasValue() == oldQ.c.HasValue() //(this is not possible?)&& newQ.b.HasValue() == oldQ.b.HasValue()
```

why is this not possible?

Comment: Use `s == null` and `s != null`?

Comment: @kafka For null check of string you can use string.IsNullOrEmpty().

Comment: i want to check whether it goes from no value to has value

Comment: No reference types have `HasValue`. Only nullable *value* types have such a thing.

Comment: Even for nullable value types you typically do not/should not use `.HasValue`. Test for (in)equality with `null`.

Comment: You always can create your own extension `HasValue`

Comment: There is no such thing as `string?` in c# version lower than `8`. Are you using `c# 8`?

Comment: `HasValue` and `Value` are ___properties___, not methods so invoking `.HasValue()` would be wrong anyway

Comment: a string is an object and not a nullable<t>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HasValue` property belongs to [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=netframework-4.8) struct, where `T` is also restricted to be a value type only. So, `HasValue` is exist only for value types.

Nullable reference types are implemented using type annotations, you can't use the same approach with nullable value types. To check a reference type for nullability you could use comparison with `null` or [`IsNullOrEmpty`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty?view=netframework-4.8) method (for strings only). So, you can rewrite your code a little bit

```cs
var oldQ = new Test() { c = 123 };
var newQ = new Test() { c = 456 };

bool isStilValid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(newQ.b) == string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldQ.b);
```

Or just use a regular comparison with `null`

```cs
bool isStilValid = (newQ.b != null) == (oldQ.b != null);
```

Comment: @phuzi Technically properties are methods.

Comment: @SᴇM: Properties are not methods. Properties are *implemented* as *a pair of methods*, but that's an implementation detail. Properties and methods are both *members*.

Comment: @EricLippert The keyword was _"Technically"_.

Comment: Lets explore further. Are events "technically methods"? Suppose a property getter is inlined 100% of the time into a field access. Is it "technically a method" then? I am interested to learn about your belief system.

Comment: @EricLippert I'm very touched by your interest in my "belief system", but I will not expand it here. I'm not saying properties **are** methods and by saying _"technically"_ - I meant _it was internally implemented as methods (setting and getting method internally cause a method call)_.  Also, if someone thinks that I said something wrong, I'm open to discussion/correction in an "appropriate discussion way".

Answer (score 1):

Only struct in C# have HasValue method, but you can simple create your own string extension as below and that will solve your problem.

```
public static class StringExtension {

    public static bool HasValue(this string value)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
    }
}
```

I hope this is helpful for someone.

Comment: fixed your typo in "struct", but also want to point out there is no such thing as "struct classes" they are either structs or classes

Comment: also IMHO your method should be renamed to `HasNonEmptyValue` to reflect that it treats empty (a value) as false

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent comparing to `null` would be:

```
bool isStillValid = (newQ.c != null) == (oldQ.c != null) && (newQ.b != null) == (oldQ.b != null);
```

That's the equivalent to your original code, but I'm not sure the original code is correct...

`isStillValid` will be true if ALL the items being tested for null are actually null. Is that really what you intended?

That is, if `newQ.c` is null and `oldQ.c` is null and `newQ.b` is null and `oldQ.b` is null then `isStillValid` will be `true`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Nullable<T>` type requires a type `T` that is a non-nullable value type for example `int` or `double`. 
`string` typed variables are already null, so the nullable string typed variable doesn't make sense.

You need to use `string.IsNullOrEmpty` or simply `null`